# SocketException Connection Reset

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, tcpsocket

I created a server which accept TCP connection . After connected to socket it looping for reading data from input stream.

**Steps:**

1. I started my server.
2. Start Client.

Now I am closing client.

Then Server gives me SocketException  Connection Reset

How do I check that my client is alive or not before reading from input stream.

Comment: Please show us what have you done so far. What is the server side and what is the Client side. Also paste the stack trace to have a better idea what really your problem is.

Comment: You will have to shoe _some_ code samples also to wee what exactly you are doing in the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server gets a 'connection reset' it is probably writing to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. A browser whose user presses the 'back' button is a good example. If this is an expected condition, ignore the exception. If it constitutes an application protocol error, debug the application.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 ways you can check if a socket is connected, you can either read or write to it, if it is connected you wont get an error, if it isnt connected you will get an error. This is how i check if a socket is connected:

```
BufferedReader reader;

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        String message;
        while((message = reader.readLine())!=null) //The thread stops here untill the reader has somthing to read
        {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
     }catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println("Client disconnected!");
         // an error is thrown when reader cannot read the stream because it is closed, you will get a connection reset error.
     }
}
```

When the Socket is connected the reader waits untill there is somthing to be read(message = reader.readLine()). When the client disconnects and the Socket is closed, the reader throws an exception because there is nothing that can be read because the stream is closed. I hope this helps!

Comment: you could also use `socket.isConnected()` and `socket.isClosed()` methods to check if the socket is still open.

Comment: Actually, if you read the discriptions for those meathods it says that the return value is this; if the socket at one point in time was connected return true, else return false. Heres a test you can do, Connect a client to a server, when the client disconnects and throws the error, check the return value of both of those meathods, they will both return true.

Comment: @Anantha Sharma: No, this is completely incorrect. Those methods tell you whether *you* have called connect() or close(). Not what the other end has done.

Comment: I just checked these methods in the scenarios mentioned by @John Detter, i found out that you both are right.. these methods only show what happened at the server side (if you closed the connection or not) & not the other way around.. I guess the only way to findout is to try to read things & look for an exception.

Comment: @Anantha Sharma they tell you what happened at *your* side, as I said; and as @John Detter said, you can either read or write. Not you've said here.

Comment: @gsfd When the client disconnects, readLine() returns null. Network exceptions occur when something really bad happens. Client disconnection isn't one of them, and it doesn't cause 'connection reset'.